# How can I check If I have access to window.opener?

Tags: javascript, window.opener

How can I check if I have access to window.opener?

I'm getting an error if I open my page in a new window from a file that is not connected with my page (`access denied`).

Code:

```
if (window.opener) {
        if (window.opener.document.getElementById('myHidden') !== "undefined") {
            if (window.opener.document.getElementById('myHidden').value == "1" && $("#inputXYZ").val() != "1") {
```

In line **2** the error occurs. But only if I open the page from a random page (that of course does not have an input field called "myHidden").
If I open the page from a "valid" page that has such an element, it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing an element instance with the **string** `"undefined"`, and you're not checking whether `window.opener.document` is present (I don't know whether you have to or not, but it's easy to add). You probably meant:

```
// Note: Still not right, see below
if (typeof window.opener.document.getElementById('myHidden') !== "undefined")
```

...except that that's still not correct, because `getElementById` returns `null` (not `undefined`) when there's no matching element.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
var input = window.opener &&
            window.opener.document &&
            window.opener.document.getElementById('myHidden');
var value = input && input.value;
if (value != "1") {
    // Do something
}
```

That uses the curiously powerful `&&` operator (close cousin to [the curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)). The first assignment will short-circuit if `window.opener` or `window.opener.document` is "falsey" (`null` or `undefined` or `0` or `""` or `NaN` or, of course, `false` -- and those last four don't apply), resulting in `input` being `undefined`. The second assignment will short-circuit if `input` is falsey, resulting in `value` being `undefined`. `undefined` != `"1"`, so...

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have access to window.opener.document:

```
if (window.opener && window.opener.document) {
        if (window.opener.document.getElementById('myHidden') !== "undefined") {
                if (window.opener.document.getElementById('myHidden').value == "1" && $("#inputXYZ").val() != "1") {
                }
        }
}
```

And if you want to be really sure add in a check for `window.opener.document.getElementById`
e.g.

```
if (window.opener && window.opener.document && window.opener.document.getElementById) {
        if (window.opener.document.getElementById('myHidden') !== "undefined") {
                if (window.opener.document.getElementById('myHidden').value == "1" && $("#inputXYZ").val() != "1") {
                }
        }
}
```